# how do i load a view(cshtml) into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor

I'm trying to load a view into an iframe in another(parent) view using javascript and razor.

I'v tried setting the iframe's src to this
 `var url = '@Url.Action("myaction", "MyController")';`

and this:
 `var url = '@Href("~/myform.cshtml")';`
without success.

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you are using razor engine.

```
<iframe src = '@Url.Action("myaction", "myController")' width = "100%" 
    height="1000" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I just tried that...didnt work. no errors just didnt load anything.

Comment: @sirbombay, can you post your controller method and js script where you are consuming it

Answer (score 1):

Set the 'src' attribute of the iframe to the action's url.

**Example:**

```
<iframe src ='home/index'></iframe>
```

Make sure you replace the URL within the `src` attribute to the URL of the action.

**An alternative way in Razor:**

```
<iframe src ='@Url.Action("action name")'></iframe>
```